# Reading death record of Margret Hasert (1624)

Tags: palaeography, church-records, kurrent, german

This is one of the earliest Hasert/Schüchel records I've found, from Mihla, Germany in 1624.  I'm having some difficulties reading it, however.

[image]

The transcription as far as I can figure it out:

```
Den 4 August begraben Margret Hasert, foust
Schüchel genannt, alte Wittibe, [ftanb?] plötzlich, fanden
zweifeln vom [reglag?] genannt, und [cattfiel?] [irf?] die
[fnrach?] in 3 Stunden, nach dem sie sich Abel befunden
hernach auch gefischt und [gefar?], [derfichiede?] [jumerfalb?]
24 stünden, ihres [alttens?] 66 Jahr.
```

I seek any assistance in getting a clear transcription and translation.  The translation I can get at the moment, given the [?] words, is pretty useless:

> The 4 August buried Margret Hasert, called Schüchel, old widow,
> [ftanb?] suddenly, found doubt of the [reglag?] called, and
> [cattfiel?] [irf?] the [fnrach?] in 3 hours, after which she found
> herself Abel also fished and [gefar?], [derfichiede?] [jumerfalb?] 24
> stand?, her [alttens?] 66 year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Den 4 Augusti begraben Margret haserten, sonst Schücheln genandt, aldte Wittibe, starb plözlich, sonder Zweiffels vom Schlag gerüret, und endtfiel ihr die Sprach in 3 Stunden, nach dem sie sich Übel befunden, hernach auch gesicht und gehör, verschiede Innerhalb 24 Stunden, ihres Aldters 66 Jahr.

On 4 August [has been] buried Margret haserten, otherwise called Schücheln, old widow, died suddenly, without doubt due to a stroke, and lost her speech after 3 hours when she [first] had felt unwell, after that also her face* [degraded] and [she lost her] hearing, died within 24 hours, aged 66 years.

*According to ad42 "Gesicht" should translate to "sight" here. See comments.

Comment: I deleted my (mostly identical) answer, but would like to make a few remarks: it is Haserten, not haserttn, and gesicht here translates as sight, not face.

Comment: I think you should have left your overlapping answer in, no harm in that. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll amend.

Comment: Thanks guys for the assist.  Tangentally, I'd agree with ad42 on "Haserten"; "-en" was the feminine surname suffix normally used in this area.